# Excel Cell Value Replacement with other value in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, excel, printing, replace

I am working on a windows application in .NET C#.  I have to replace Excel cell content with some other text (that I am getting from a database).  What I need to do is to replace the values of Excel with the actual values from the database. (e.g. "CustomerName" would be replaced by "John", "CustomerCompanyName" would be replaced by "GE" etc. ). Also if some values are not present then that empty space would be overlapped by its below values.

How can we implement this thing?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If these are just static values in a worksheet and you do not expect calculations to be performed in excel when you update them then just use [OpenXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358824.aspx)  to edit the spreadsheet.

Otherwise you will have to use Office Interopt or some third party excel library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FlexCel from http://www.tmssoftware.net/ (no affiliation) and it's great. Reasonably priced, fast, all managed code and the developer seems to know what he's talking about and very responsive to queries too.

1000% better than the OFfice Interop libraries IMHO.

In the past I've accessed Excel through Interop libraries and for servers I've used the ODBC/OLE-DB driver but there were always difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use OpenXml, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298534%28v=office.14%29) you'll find how to read the values of the cells of your Excel document, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc861607%28v=office.14%29) one for writing the values in a cell.

Another free library you can use is [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). These instructions give you a first idea of how to read/write cells' data and save the modified file:

```
        FileStream aFile = new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\foo.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(aFile);
        aFile.Close();
        ISheet ws = wb.GetSheet("Worksheet1");

        IRow aRow = curSheet.GetRow(aRowIdx);
        if (aRow == null)
            aRow = curSheet.CreateRow(aRowIdx);
        ICell aCell = aRow.GetCell(aColIdx);
        if (aCell == null)
            aCell = aRow.CreateCell(aColIdx);
        string sValue = aCell.StringCellValue; // here the value is read
        sValue = sValue + " MODIFIED";
        aCell.SetCellValue(sValue); // here it is written
        aFile = new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\bar.xls", FileMode.Create);
        wb.Write(aFile);
        aFile.Close();
```